# Is there a way to restore software classes registry keys

Tags: windows-vista, boot, windows-registry, restore

I accidentally deleted registry keys under hkey_current_user>software>classes. The classes folder got completely deleted. The moment I did that system stopped functioning properly.

And, since then system doesn't boot up to login screen. A black screen with pointer appears. I tried system repair but it din't work. I could transfer files from C Drive to external Drive.

In safe mode it loads drivers list but gets "Stuck" on aswrvrt.sys where it stays for 20-30 seconds.  It then shows the "Starting Windows" screen for 20-30 seconds then all I see on the black screen is the mouse cursor.

I can see the Registry editor using cmd.exe. Is there a way I can restore previous registries or copy files externally?

Comment: " I tried system repair but it din't work" - Did you mean System Restore?